# What's the difference between ensure_future and create_task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Please explain to me when should I use `asyncio.ensure_future` and `create_task` and what's the difference.

We can write like this:

```
async def run(r):
    url = "http://localhost:8080/{}"
    tasks = []

    # Fetch all responses within one Client session,
    # keep connection alive for all requests.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        # you now have all response bodies in this variable
        print(responses)
```

Or like this:

```
async def get_all(*names: str):
    started_at = time.time()

    # Create tasks, so we start requesting all of them concurrently
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_pokemon(name)) for name in names]

    # Await ALL
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    for result in results:
        if result:
            pokemon = parse_pokemon(result)
            print(f" {pokemon.name} is of type(s) {','.join(pokemon.types)}")
        else:
            print(f"❌ No data found for...")
```

Comment: I don't get it. You are using [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) in both cases. Seems like you are more interested in the difference between [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) and [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), no? Also, what part of the documentation specifically do you not understand? I find it fairly well explained.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Danii maybe Im really dont get it. I will edit my quest. Thks my friend!